# Optimal Price Metric for High-Frequency Volatility: Executed Price, Mid Price, or Weighted Mid Price?

Tags: volatility, high-frequency, high-frequency-estimators

In the context of high frequency trading, I'm exploring the application of the mean absolute deviation estimate for high-frequency volatility calculation. What would be the optimal choice for this calculation:

1. the executed price associated with each executed message
2. the mid price associated with each tick
3. the weighted mid price associated with each tick

If you have any other suggestions, I am open to explore the alternatives.

Thank you.